# Integração contínua TFS/Azure e connection string em app.config

Tags: .net, team-foundation-server, microsoft-azure

Tenho um projeto composto por dois subprojetos, um desses subprojetos é uma `Class Library`, responsável pelas atividades de conexão a banco. Estou usando Entity Framework como ferramenta de ORM.

No arquivo `app.config`, tenho a seguinte connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DB.Context" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DB.Context;Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Nada muito complexo, apenas aponta para um banco de dados local.

No entanto, na hora do deploy desta aplicação para produção (através da publicação a partir do controle de versão do Azure), não consigo fazer com que essa connection string seja atualizada automaticamente para apontar para o BD de produção. Tenho a cadeia de conexão configurada no meu painel:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso conseguir que **a string de conexão presente no app.config seja atualizada durante a publicação a partir do TFS, no Azure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiago,

O app.config não se transforma durante o processo de deploy - publishing (existe como fazer isso, apenas via Visual Studio, mas não é nativo até a versão VS2013).

Suas configurações de ConnectioString deve ficar na aplicação, então, no web.config.

Esse é um dos motivos que não há transformação em sua implementação contínua.

Comment: Realmente, depois de muito tempo percebi que posso deixar essas configurações no web.config, o Entity Framework se resolve bem puxando a informação de lá, mesmo que esteja localizado em um projeto diferente :)

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira legal que ajudou. Se concordar, marque a resposta que melhor ajudou a sua dúvida para que outros com a mesma dúvida possam tomar como orientação. (y)

Answer (score 1):

[Este blog mostra um passo a passo para o Web.config](http://blog.degree.no/2012/03/automatic-config-transformations/). Como transformações se aplicam a todos os arquivos do projeto, se você tiver instalado [esta extensão do Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) tem uma boa chance de funcionar.

Como não testei, não posso afirmar 100%.